# Entity Framework | Include -> Select Empty Field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with our Select.

But first, we have 3 tables:
for example:

inventory,
items,
device_properties

The inventory have Items. And a few of the Items have device_properties.

The items and the device_properties doesnt change. In this case we include fix the device_properties to the items.

Now at the call we want to get the inventory, and include at the request an include from items to the inventory entries.

Now the problem is, if we request it, we send data like x.items.device_properties.name
But this can be null. And if this is null it doesnt work because:

```
nullable object must have a value
```

and if i do like the following, he needs to long:

```c
deviceName = x.items.device_properties == null ? "" : x.items.device_properties.name
```

```c
var items = db.inventory.Where(x => x.itemName== itemName).Include(i => i.items).Select(x => new
{
  itemId = x.id,
  x.itemName,
  deviceName = x.items.device_properties.name
}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

At this i get the message, that the nullable needs a value.
And if i do it like:

```c
var items = db.inventory.Where(x => x.itemName== itemName).Include(i => i.items).Select(x => new
{
  itemId = x.id,
  x.itemName,
  deviceName = x.items.device_properties == null ? "" : x.items.device_properties.name
}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

The query needs a lot longer

message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value
```

Comment: some code that causes an error would be helpful.  Please read about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? What is the type of `x.items`? In general, expression like `x.items.device_properties.name` won't generate NRE if evaluated server side (database, SQL).

Comment: the field i used is an int. And this makes the problem. i did now from int and int? Now it works

Answer (score 0):

In addition `device_properties` should not be `null`, you should check `items` property should not be `null`.

```cs
var items = db.inventory.Where(x => x.itemName== itemName).Include(i => i.items).Select(x => new
{
  itemId = x.id,
  x.itemName,
  deviceName = x.items == null || x.items.device_properties == null ? "" : x.items.device_properties.name
}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```